# utf-8 sequence in the console

Tags: console, unicode, tree

when I perform the "tree" command in the console, here's what I've got :

```
.
├── Annexe\ 1\ -\ Sch\303\251ma\ global\ de\ la\ base\ de\ donn\303\251es.raw
...
```

The result is composed of utf-8 sequences, I need to get the string in a human-readable form for a report.
How can I convert that nasty thing ?

Comment: You can try exporting `LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: There is no change.

Comment: What does the `locale` command report?

Comment: What's the output of `printf %s Annex*.raw | hd`?

Comment: In which console? Linux?

Answer (score 6):

You can specify any character set you want it to use with the `--charset` switch.

```
   --charset charset
          Set the character set to use when outputting HTML and for line 
          drawing.
```

There are also these 2 switches which may help:

```
   -q     Print non-printable characters in filenames as question marks 
          instead of the default.

   -N     Print non-printable characters as is instead of as escaped octal 
          numbers.
```

Also you can augment the output using these switches:

```
   -A     Turn on ANSI line graphics hack when printing the indentation 
          lines.

   -S     Turn on ASCII line graphics (useful when using Linux console mode 
          fonts). This option is now equivalent to `--charset=IBM437' and 
          may eventually be depreciated.
```

Answer (score 2):

I can get that output with:

```
LC_ALL=C tree -A
```

You'd see `\303\251` if `tree` thought that 0303 and 0251 were not valid characters (or sequence of character in your locale).

However that is valid in UTF-8 locales where `\303\251` is `é` and in iso-8859-1 or iso-8859-15 (the two common single byte per character charsets that are common in French speaking countries) where `\303` is `Ã` and `\251` is `©`.

So, here that suggests you're in a locale where the charset is defined only for the first 128 byte values like ASCII is like in the C locale.

You could tell `tree` that your charset is UTF-8 or iso-8859-15, and then it would not translate those 0303 bytes to  `\303`.

`locale -a` will tell you if there's a locale on your system with a UTF-8 charset. Then you can pick one like `fr_FR.UTF-8`:

```
LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 tree
```

But then, whether it's going to be displayed properly or not will depend on what your terminal emulator understands. If it's not configured to display UTF-8 characters, it won't work.

If your terminal emulator is able to display iso-8859-1, you could make `tree` display UTF-8 and convert that with `iconv`:

```
LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 tree | iconv -f UTF-8
```